# Parse Query returns null

Tags: android, parse-platform

Hello there below is the snippet of my code . I am trying to query on parse user class and it always returns null . Any help from your side will be appreciated .

```
    public ParseUser getFriend(String name)
    {
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("Name", name);
    try {
        ParseUser user = query.getFirst();
        return  user;
    } catch (com.parse.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return  null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code looks ok. You are of course certain that your name column is in fact "Name" and not "name" and that the value in your name parameter is found in your parse table?

Comment: yahh my column is Name and the parm value matches the value in the column when i statically pass value in third line it works properly but cant get output when getting value from parm name .

Comment: And you've tried logging the contents of the "name" parameter right before you use it in whereEqualTo?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 public ParseObject getFriend(String name)
{
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.whereEqualTo("Name", name);
try {
    ParseObject user = query.getFirst();
    return  user;
} catch (com.parse.ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return  null;
}
```